# Processing abandoned The video could not be processed - Youtube API?

Tags: django, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am uploading mp4 videos through my website using youtube data v3 api and the http post request looks like:

```
access_token = request.session['access_token']
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet"

    payload = {
        'snippet':{
            "categoryId": "22",
            "description": "Description of uploaded video.",
            "title": "Test video upload."
        }
    }
    files = [
        ('media_body', request.FILES['media_body'])
    ]
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token,
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))

    context = {
        'r': response
    }
    return render_to_response('dashboard/manage_content/youtube.html', context)
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{ "kind": "youtube#video", "etag": "yS7DhsHOhsDM-vXZiGUmLXcKST0", "id": "dII224dYC2o", "snippet": { "publishedAt": "2020-07-03T12:11:43Z", "channelId": "UCmv2Sec30iBc13b7ntf93Ow", "title": "unknown", "description": "", "thumbnails": { "default": { "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dII224dYC2o/default.jpg", "width": 120, "height": 90 }, "medium": { "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dII224dYC2o/mqdefault.jpg", "width": 320, "height": 180 }, "high": { "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dII224dYC2o/hqdefault.jpg", "width": 480, "height": 360 } }, "channelTitle": "Nikhil Dhoot", "categoryId": "20", "liveBroadcastContent": "none", "localized": { "title": "unknown", "description": "" } } }
```

But on the videos tab, I get the error: Processing abandoned The video could not be processed.
The fact that the video responds a success message means that all the authentication process before it has been successful. However, if required I can edit and share that code too.

Comment: Actually, we abandoned the whole idea because youtube api has a lot of complications and now they have made some strict rules from 29th June (I think). But your answer seems apt so I'll mark it correct. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading a video to YouTube is a two-step process:

1. Invoke the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint, posting to that a proper [JSON text describing](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body) your video.
2. Upon the API call, get the location where to actually upload the video content from the API endpoint response. Then do the actual content uploading operation.

Do scrutinize the [source code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py) Google made publicly available w.r.t uploading videos on YouTube. You'll learn all the concrete details of the algorithm I sketched above.

If you'd like to go deeper into how the call `request.next_chunk()` in function `resumable_upload` works, then go read the relevant part -- the method `HttpRequest.next_chunk` -- in file [`http.py`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py) of Google's API Client Library for Python.

Comment: So I need to call two endpoints for the uploading procedure, one for relevant information about the video and the next one should have media_body which uploads the entire video? I actually tried my above code on postman and it worked perfectly fine - video information and the actual file in the same API call. I am going for a simple upload rather than a resumable one. Would resumable be a better choice?

Comment: The two-step process I described above constitutes the basic logic that any API client has to implement one way or the other. (As a side note: the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) do not bother at all documenting this process). Note that different client libraries may choose to implement the upload procedure (step (1) and (2)) such that to alleviate their users of cumbersome details -- thus hiding step (2) away, making library users life easier.

Comment: With respect to using or not the resumable uploading feature, I'd say that it depends. If you have a reliable and fast Internet connection then you may upload videos in one go. Using that feature, however, enables you to retry uploading any chunk that failed previously (thus avoiding the abort of the entire upload process). Also take into account the length of your video file too. At the end of (1) + (2), any failed upload is accounted by the API as a completed upload operation, thus costing you 1600 (plus a few more extra) units of quota.

Comment: Furthermore, here is what the Google developer noted along the `initialize_upload` function in [`upload_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/07263305b59a7c3275bc7e925f9ce6cabf774022/python/upload_video.py#L83) sample code [part I]: `The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower value for better recovery on less reliable connections.`

Comment: Part II: `Setting 'chunksize' equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails, it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).`

Comment: I have to correct one of my statements above: Google in fact **does document** [the uploading procedure](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol), only that the `Videos.insert` [API doc page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) doesn't link (refer) to that documentation.

Comment: They went with a really lengthy process. I'll try going through the resumable route and will update accordingly. Thanks a lot for explaining the procedure. Honestly, this was easier to understand than the official documentation.

Comment: The quick start guide in google page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) seems to provide the same error of "processing abandoned"

Comment: @Avirup Das: please follow the recommendation given by [this answer I gave recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763037/8327971). Also post a comment containing the entire output provided by issuing the following two commands at a command line prompt: `python3 --version` and `openssl version -a`.

Comment: My Bad... The video file got corrupted while moving across drives. As a result the same was not processed.