# Python MemoryError when uploading big video through YouTube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Getting `MemoryError` while trying to upload a large video file to YouTube. When uploading smaller file it is okay but when the file is bigger I get `MemoryError`. I guess it's because code tries to load video file to RAM. Is there any way to upload a video without loading it to RAM.

```
import os
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"]


def main():
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "0"

    client_secret_file = 'client_credentials.json'
    api_name = 'youtube'
    api_version = 'v3'

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secret_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part='snippet,status',
        body={
            'snippet': {
                'categoryId': "20",
                'title': 'test title',
                'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'private'
            }
        },
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(File Path)
    )

    response = request.execute()

    print(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This was my first question in stackoverflow. Thank for your answer. I've copied the code from official YouTube script but changed it a little bit course I don't know how to work with 'parsed', 'args'. It actually solved the memory error problem though.

Comment: If having problems with `argparse` module's functionalities then you may well open a new question attaching to it the tags: [tag:argparse] and [tag:python].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your `MemoryError` exception is the following: your input video file [gets loaded in memory](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/32d1c597b364e2641eca33ccf6df802bb218eea1/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L1126) in its entirety prior of being processed for to be sent off to the remote service:

```py
def createMethod(methodName, methodDesc, rootDesc, schema):
    ...
    def method(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        if media_filename:
            ...
            if media_upload.resumable():
                ...
            else:
                # A non-resumable upload
                if body is None:
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
                    payload = media_upload.getbytes(0, media_upload.size())
                    ...
```

Instead of uploading videos in one go, I'd very much recommend to use [resumable uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720189/8327971) by means of the time-tested public Google script [`upload_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py). (This script has an [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) too. To obtain a self-explanatory usage information page from the script just issue it with the command line option `--help`.)

---

If you're using Python 3 (your code suggests that) then you have to convert that script to Python 3, because it's written for Python 2. For this, see the section *Patching `upload_video.py`* of [one answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763037/8327971).

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add closing quotes on your doc string

Comment: No, didn't forget, only that the code excerpt above intends to indicate a context (there's a couple of ellipses that truncate the code shown a lot). I removed that line to alleviate confusions.